# Создание очереди на сайте

Tags: php, mysql, ddos

Есть один сайт, на который временами накладывается большая нагрузка. 
Сервер эту нагрузку не выдерживает. (1000 одновременных посетителей на сайте).
Скажите, какой алгоритм можно придумать, чтобы при критической нагрузке (как-то сервер должен дать эту информацию) пользователей перекидывало на страницу с надписью "вы такой-то в очереди", когда его очередь подходит при обновлении страницы он может попасть на основную страницу.

Скажите какой алгоритм для этого сценария можно использовать?
Выдача такой страницы думаю не будет создавать большой нагрузки. 
Вопрос как создать очередь? Использовать другую Mysql, а пользователя хранить в сессии?
В общем буду рад любой информации по данной теме.

UPD: Вопрос больше теоретический, на практике конечно нужно усиливать мощности серверов. Видел такое на kassir.ru, поэтому стал интересен этот вопрос

UPD2: Как это делали на сайте ФИФА?

Comment: Я бы начал с поиска узких мест в коде. Если не поможет, докупил бы ресурсов у хостера. 1000 одновременных коннектов - это хорошая посещаемость, которая, по идее, должна окупать затраты на хостинг.

Comment: Решение с очередью плохое как минимум по двум причинам. 1) Это реально сложная доработка 2) Я бы сразу закрыл вкладку, где мне предлагают постоять в очереди и больше бы на эту страницу не заходил.

Comment: Так а в чём сложность доработки? Очереди это нормальная практика. Данные для пользователей генерируются? Может это статика или кэшировать хотя бы? Ну а для очередей можно использовать например https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html Хотя лучше занять чем-то полезным пользователей, если уж они зашли на сайт. В игру пусть поиграют))

Comment: Это не про очереди типа rabbitmq, это просто топик про то, что сервер сайт написан неоптимально и при нагрузке тормозит.

Comment: Сначала задайтесь вопросом, что на вашем сайте является законченной сессией работы пользователя. Как вы планируете считать текущих активных юзеров и выводить их из этого статуса. После этого не сложно навернуть где-то в БД или в памяти счётчик, и просто не давать ему превышать значение лимита.

Comment: В этом и заключается вопрос.